# Button to set different activity colour

Tags: java, android, layout, background, nullpointerexception

I am trying to set the background colour of a different activity from the activity main but I am getting a null pointer.

This is the main:

```
View activity;
activity = findViewById(R.layout.activity_connect_four);
```

The button:

```
Button highScoreButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bgc);
highScoreButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick (View v) {
        // null pointer on below line
        activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content)
                .setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);                   
    }
});
```

The logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.con4.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:80)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Where the logCat is pointing to, I don't know what to change. Any help I would be grateful

Comment: Do you want to change your activity background according to clicked button ?

Comment: yes, I just wanted to test it. So I want the activity 'activity_connect_four' to have a black background after the user clicks the button. My aim is to allow the user to set the background colour of all the activities from an options menu.

Comment: A layout is not a view, so findViewById will not work. You will need to use SharedPreferrences or startActivityForResult with onActivityResult. Then usd getContentView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're receiving a NPE because that activity and view is not inflated, therefore it returns as null. The way you're setting the background color is flawed by nature. By setting it as you are, even without the NPE, you're storing a setting in the memory of the device. The moment that the device kills your activity, you'll lose that information. As an alternative, you need to store this setting on the device for later retrieval. For what you're attempting to do, I would recommend using SharedPreferences.

In your settings Activity:

```
Button highScoreButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bgc);
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
highScoreButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick (View v) {
        prefs.edit().putInt(BACKGROUND_COLOR, Color.BLACK).commit();             
    }
});
```

BACKGROUND_COLOR is a key variable that could be set to "background_color". Then when you start you other activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int color = prefs.getInt(BACKGROUND_COLOR, Color.WHITE);
```

And use that color to set the background. Using this method, the background color will be saved to the device until it gets overridden (settings change) or the app is uninstalled.

If you want this to be the background of all of your activity, I suggest having all activities extending a base activity and implementing that code there.

You can check out other storage methods here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html